# Warning on Kubeadm init - No validator is available

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubeadm

I'm trying to setup a minimum viable kubernetes cluster using kubeadm.
On invoking `kubeadm init` command i'm getting following warning.

> W0218 23:13:59.411414   25332 validation.go:28] Cannot validate
>   kube-proxy config - no validator is available
>
> W0218 23:13:59.411496   25332 validation.go:28] Cannot validate
>   kubelet config - no validator is available

What this exactly this warning means? Where can i find these validators?

I've gone through couple of links and everyone suggesting to ignore it. But i would really like to know why this warning coming up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1913)

> Define policy around klog.Warning usage in kubeadm #1913

And there is a workaround:

## Try `kubeadm reset`

Manual: [kubeadm reset - Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/)

`kubeadm reset`

pls [note](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1913#issuecomment-587588108):

> The reset process does not clean CNI configuration. To do so, you must remove /etc/cni/net.d
>
> The reset process does not reset or clean up iptables rules or IPVS tables.
>   If you wish to reset iptables, you must do so manually by using the "iptables" command.
>
> If your cluster was setup to utilize IPVS, run ipvsadm --clear (or similar)
>   to reset your system's IPVS tables.

## If it doesn't help, you may hide warnings from console out

[polarapfel](https://github.com/polarapfel) recommends to [hide warnings](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1913#issuecomment-572819116) :)

> Here's a quick fix to folks being thrown off by this behaviour in their automation scripts: redirect stderr to /dev/null (or elsewhere).
>
> For example, if you wanted the join command, you'd do this

`kubeadm token create --print-join-command 2>/dev/null`